# Windows 7 to Ubuntu 13.10 Remote Desktop NO AUDIO

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, ubuntu-13.10

I have connected to Ubuntu 13.10 from Windows & using xrdp. I have also checked the local setting audio option "Play on this computer",still i am not able to get audio on Windows.

.